# Not able to execute loop based on thread.sleep

Tags: android

I'm trying to display a series of images from a specific folder in sdcard - in the form of slideshow. **filelist[]** contains names of all files present in that directory.

I'm filtering out the images here. Next, thread.sleep(1000) does not seem to have any effect. Only the last image in the directory is displayed after a time of 1000ms. Where am I going wrong? Any other way I could accomplish this?

Maybe I've gone completely wrong. I'm a newbie so plz help.

```
public class List_imgActivity extends Activity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */

Bitmap[] bitmapArray = new Bitmap[1000];

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button pf=(Button) findViewById(R.id.pick_button);

    pf.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent("org.openintents.action.PICK_DIRECTORY");

            intent.setData(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard"));
            intent.putExtra("org.openintents.extra.TITLE", "Please select a folder");
            intent.putExtra("org.openintents.extra.BUTTON_TEXT", "Use this folder");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

        }

        });

    }
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int recievecode, Intent intent)
{

    if (requestCode == 1 )

   {
      Uri uri = intent.getData();

      try {
        File f=new File(new URI(uri.toString()));
        final String nx=f.toString();

        if(f.isDirectory()) {

            File filelist[] = f.listFiles();




        for(int i=0;i<filelist.length;i++) 
        {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        String filename = filelist[i].getName(); 
        int pos = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
        String ext = filename.substring(pos);


        if(ext.equals(".jpg"))
        {
            TextView tv1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv1.setText(filelist[i].toString());


            ImageView iv1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);





        bitmapArray[i] =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filelist[i].toString());

        iv1.setImageBitmap(bitmapArray[i]);


        }

        }


        }



    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }





   }

   } 

}
```

Comment: post whole activity code. and if you are using any thread be sure your changes on imageview done on UI Thread not in worker thread.

Comment: Are you sure filelist has more than 1 image in it?  If you are filtering the list before the loop, is it possible you've somehow filtered out everything but the last image?

Comment: Hi There, 

you can try TimerTask.

Comment: Full activity code posted(edit). Yes, filelist[] has more than 1 image in it. I can print them in a textview.

Comment: Are the extensions all exactly .jpg (ie. all lower-cased jpg)?

Comment: yes. Currently, I've put all files with lower-cased .jpg

Answer (score 1):

In Android behaviour like this will make the UI-Thread sleep. This will freeze the whole UI of the phone your App will look crashed to the user and the System will automatically kill your application after a while.

There is a mechanism to change things in specific time intervalls. You should use this handlers for doing this.  [Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

A handler has a [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) and [sendMessageDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessageDelayed%28android.os.Message,%20long%29) methods that allow you to either build a Runnable that will be executed after a certain time or send a message that must be handled by the implementation of your handler.

The initialization of the handler would look something like this:

```
showNextImageHandler = new Handler() {  
   @Override
   public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
      showNextImage();
   }
};

showNextImageHandler.sendMessageDelayed(showNextImageHandler.obtainMessage(), 1000);
```

This code creates a new handler that calls the function showNextImage every time it receives a message. I would store the Handler in an instance variable of your activity to send further messages later on. After the handler is created a first empty message is send in a way that will delay the posting of the message 1000 milliseconds. After a second the showNextImage function will be called. In this function you can change the view and if a next image exists you can post another delayed message to trigger another call to the function later on.

Answer (score 0):

U Must synchronise the current object before applying Thread.sleep() method